# When testing IAP in PlayStore, how do I know I'm on a test account?

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I added an alpha tester account on Google Developer Console to test the IAPs in my Android app. However, I'm not sure if I'm indeed on a tester account when trying to purchase something.

When clicking on a button to purchase something, I got the usual pop-up with the name of the product, the price, and a **Continue** button, but no indications that I'm using a tester account and that I'll not be charged any money.

Is this normal behavior, or should some kind of indication be displayed and I'm missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll show text like "You are in test purchase mode", or something like that. To add your account to testing ones, you need to add your phone's email (main phone email, that used in Play Store) in Play Developer Console in account settings, there will be field "Gmail accounts for testing"